# diverting a http request to two files via apache setting

Tags: php, apache, http

I am receiving the http request in apache which is handled via a php file. Is there way(by some setting in apache) that same request can be bifurcated to two php files where they can be processed simultaneously and in parallel. Will it cause any performance issue??

Comment: wow, why might you need this?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by sending the request to two php files?

Comment: the request are coming at the rate 5/sec and the php file need more that 5sec to process one request, so that may result in missing out some requests.

Comment: How would you separate a business process in a file to two file? This is a very complicated! Isn't it better to increase the php process time instead!

Comment: i have designed the logic for that. Dont wrry for that

Comment: You logic may not work the way you want. Anyway, is your call from an html or it's automatic?

Comment: I searched a bit but I didn't find any recommended way. I thought of embedding another request in an Iframe or maybe calling the url of the second script within the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a very odd set up, you should be able to process up to thousands of requests per second.

Apache (assuming a standard set up) spawns a new worker thread for each request, then the thread handles the request. So if you have a php script handling the request, then it will handle the request inside that thread.

PHP scripts are not locked, they are interpreted and executed by the PHP runtime when the server handles the request, this means that a single script can be running in multiple threads.

For example, the application that I work on at my job consists of hundreds of PHP files all working together and the application fields 1000's of requests per second, this all on a mostly standard LAMP set up (we have some extra's, like XHProf).

Comment: Agreed, what if the all the thread are accessing the same conf file and log file. will they wait for the first thread to finish off and free up the resources?

Comment: Well it depends on the operation. If it is reading, then the OS can generally make it look like it's reading simultaneously. Writing can lock the file (depending on the OS), but if you're worried about that, then write to a temporary file and copy to the destination. This works if you are continuously writing over a long period of time.  It seems that you are over-thinking this somewhat, try it the simple way, then fix it if it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPd already does this unless you're running PHP as CGI or some other special single-process mode.